# Copying a Django Field description from an existing Model to a new one

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to dynamically generate a new Model, based on fields from an existing Model. Both are defined in `/apps/main/models.py`. The existing model looks something like this:

```
from django.db import models

class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    height = models.IntegerField()
```

I have a list containing the names of fields that I would like to copy:

```
target_fields = ["name", "age"]
```

I want to generate a new model the has all of the Fields named in `target_fields`, but in this case they should be indexed (`db_index = True`).

I originally hoped that I would just be able to iterate over the class properties of `People` and use `copy.copy` to copy the field descriptions that are defined on it. Like this:

```
from copy import copy

d = {}
for field_name in target_fields:
    old_field = getattr(People, field_name) # alas, AttributeError
    new_field = copy(old_field)
    new_field.db_index = True
    d[field_name] = new_field

IndexedPeople = type("IndexedPeople", (models.Model,), d)
```

I wasn't sure if `copy.copy()`ing Fields would work, but I didn't get far enough to find out: the fields listed in the class definition don't aren't actually included as properties on the class object. I assume they're used for some metaclass shenanigans instead.

After poking around in the debugger, I found some type of Field objects listed in `People._meta.local_fields`. However, these aren't just simple description that can be `copy.copy()`ed and used to describe another model. For example, they include a `.model` property referring to `People`.

How can I create a field description for a new model based on a field of an existing model?

Comment: "dynamically generate a new Model" The future you would like to have a word with you...

Comment: what use case requires a dynamic model?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams This is a pared-down example, but the plan is to generate secondary tables indexing fields from the primary, similar to what was described in [How FriendFeed uses MySQL to store schema-less data](http://backchannel.org/blog/friendfeed-schemaless-mysql). The primary models will be used in most cases, but some requests will be handled using the model with the most suitable index instead. (The secondary models will have a `ForeignKey` referencing the first.) These facts are relevant to my motivation but not the core technical question; I thought they would be a distraction.

Comment: That article discusses creating new tables. Django models are not tables, they're an abstraction onto the database. Django's ORM is not prepared to perform the tasks you need done in order to implement this cleanly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From poking around in the debugger and the source: all Django models use the `ModelBase` metaclass defined in [`/db/models/base.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.1/django/db/models/base.py). For each field in a model's class definition, `ModelBase`'s `.add_to_class` method will call the field's `.contribute_to_class` method.

`Field.contribute_to_class` is defined in [`/db/models/fields/__init__.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.1/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py) and it is what's responsible for associating a field definition with a particular model. The field is modified by adding the `.model` property and by calling the `.set_attributes_from_name` method with the name used in the model's class definition. This in turn adds adds the `.attname` and `.column` properties and sets `.name` and `.verbose_name` if necessary.

When I inspect the `__dict__` property of a newly-defined `CharField` and compare it with that of a `CharField` that was already associated with a model, I also see that these are the only differences:

- The `.creation_counter` property is unique for each instance.
- The `.attrname`, `.column` and `.model` properties do not exist on the new instance.
- The `.name` and `.verbose_name` properties is `None` on the new instance.

It doesn't seem possible to distinguish between `.name`/`.verbose_name` properties that were manually specified to the constructor and ones that were automatically generated. You'll need to chose either to always reset them, ignoring any manually-specified values, or never clear them, which would cause them to always ignore any new name they were given in the new model. I want to use the same name as the original fields, so I am not going to touch them.

Knowing what differences exist, I am using `copy.copy()` to clone the existing instance, then apply these changes to make it behave like a new instance.

```
import copy
from django.db import models

def copy_field(f):
    fp = copy.copy(f)

    fp.creation_counter = models.Field.creation_counter
    models.Field.creation_counter += 1

    if hasattr(f, "model"):
        del fp.attname
        del fp.column
        del fp.model

        # you may set .name and .verbose_name to None here

    return fp
```

Given this function, I create the new Model with the following:

```
target_field_name = "name"

target_field = People._meta.get_field_by_name(target_field_name)[0]
model_fields = {}

model_fields["value"] = copy_field(target_field)
model_fields["value"].db_index = True
model_fields["__module__"] = People.__module__

NewModel = type("People_index_" + field_name, (models.Model,), model_fields)
```

It works!

Answer (score 4):

### Solution

There is build in way for fields copying `Field.clone()` - method which deconstructs field removing any model dependent references:

```py
    def clone(self):
        """
        Uses deconstruct() to clone a new copy of this Field.
        Will not preserve any class attachments/attribute names.
        """
        name, path, args, kwargs = self.deconstruct()
        return self.__class__(*args, **kwargs)
```

So you can use following util to copy fields ensuring that you'll not accidentally affect source fields of model you're copying from:

```py
def get_field(model, name, **kwargs):
    field = model._meta.get_field(name)
    field_copy = field.clone()
    field_copy.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    return field_copy
```

Also can pass some regular kwargs like verbose_name and etc:

```py
def get_field_as_nullable(*args, **kwargs):
    return get_field(*args, null=True, blank=True, **kwargs)
```

**Does not work for m2m fields inside of model definition.** (m2m.clone() on model definition raises `AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet`)

### Why this instead of abstract models?

Well, depends on case. Some times you don't need inheristance but **actuall fields copying**. When? For example:

I have a User model and model which represents an application (document for user data update request) for user data update:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = ...
    last_name = ...
    email = ...
    phone_number = ...
    birth_address = ...
    sex = ...
    age = ...
    representative = ...
    identity_document = ...


class UserDataUpdateApplication(models.Model):
    # This application must ONLY update these fields.
    # These fiends must be absolute copies from User model fields.
    user_first_name = ...
    user_last_name = ...
    user_email = ...
    user_phone_number = ...
```

So, i **shouldn't** carry out duplicated fields from my User model to abstract class due to the fact that some **other non-user-logic-extending model** wants to have **exact same fields**. Why? Because it's not **directly** related to User model - User model **shouldn't** care what depends on it (excluding cases when you want to **extend User model**), so it shouldn't be separated due to fact that some other model **with it's own non User related logic** want's to have exact same fields.

Instead you can do this:

```py
class UserDataUpdateApplication(models.Model):
    # This application must ONLY update these fields.
    user_first_name = get_field(User, 'first_name')
    user_last_name =  get_field(User, 'last_name')
    user_email =  get_field(User, 'user_email')
    user_phone_number =  get_field(User, 'phone_number')
```

You also would make som util which would generate some abc class "on fly" to avoid code duplication:

```
class UserDataUpdateApplication(
    generate_abc_for_model(
        User,
        fields=['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number'],
        prefix_fields_with='user_'),
    models.Model,
):
    pass
```