# How to copy a field instance of a model and register it on another model in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to generate models that record some fields of other models, using metaclass.

My plan is to copy `recording_fields` of `recording_model`(which is a model to be recorded), and register them on the subclasses of `RecordModel` via `contribute_to_class(cls,name)` method of *django*'s `Field`.

In this way, it will be able to automatically create records whenever one of `recording_model`'s `recording_fields` has been changed, using signals.

The problem is that I have to create exactly same `Field` instances with `recording_model`'s, including database constraints and requirements (e.g. `max_length` argument).

So the situation is

```
from django.models import Model
from django.models.base import ModelBase


class TimeStampedModel(Model):

    ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ...


class RecordModelMetaClass(ModelBase):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        ...

        # Register 'recording_fields' of 'recording_model'
        # to subclasses of RecordModel (not reference, deep copy)
        # using `contribute_to_class`.

        ...


class RecordModel(TimeStampedModel):
    __metaclass__ = RecordModelMetaClass

    recording_model = NotImplemented
    recording_fields = NotImplemented

    class Meta(TimeStampedModel.Meta):
        abstract = True
```

where `RecordModel` will be the abstract base class of all records.

I know I can use `Model._meta.get_field()` method to retrieve an `Field` instance of a model, but what I need is copy of an instance, not reference.

**Is there any way to make an deep copy of an `Field` instance in django?**

Comment: Have you seen the answer to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222003/copying-a-django-field-description-from-an-existing-model-to-a-new-one