# Reuse Django field definitions in other models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm having a few fields throughout different models. E.g.

```
class A(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False)
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    field_3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)

class B(models.Model):
    field_4 = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False)
    field_5 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    field_6 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
```

In addition of these classes, I want to create a lead class. This class contains data that will be potentially copied into the other models in the future. The data constraints are therefore the same but since this is optional data, some might be missing.

I want to use DRY, but I also want to update the blank field. Any tips on how to use the exact field definitions from those original classes?

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    field_1 = A.field_1  # but with updated blank field
    field_3 = B.field_3  # but with updated blank field
```

I considered class dependency, but in reality I'm using fields from 5 classes which I fear will become an unreadable mess if the lead class depends on these.

Comment: have you tried to create an abstract class and use it for others?

Comment: @amadou-sow, yes I did as mentioned in the last paragraph. However I thought this might become difficult to read. On top of that, changing the blank to True/False is more difficult to do in that scenario.

Comment: From reading more into the Django documentation, I'm starting to believe that it is not possible. "In normal Python class inheritance, it is permissible for a child class to override any attribute from the parent class. In Django, this isn’t usually permitted for model fields." - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted

Answer (score 1):

## Django ORM

Since Django adds a layer on top of Python, class dependency works differently. Just referring to a field definition from another non-abstract class and overwriting fields is [not allowed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted) as it would break the database or introduce nasty bugs.

## Solution

Instead of referring to the function, copy it using the built in function `clone()`.

```
# Create a new function to gather the field definition from another model
def get_field_from_model(model, field):
    return model._meta.get_field(field)


def modify_field(base_model, base_field, **kwargs):
    field = get_field_from_model(base_model, base_field)
    field_copy = field.clone()
    field_copy.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    return field_copy
```

Officially _meta a hidden class but it is considered stable and an [official API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/). However, I put it in a separate function for quick access if this changes. This approach is based on the more elaborate answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54902377/3768552) (solution is similar, original question focussed on copying fields from variables rather than in the class definition).

## Implementation

Now this function can be used in the class definition. It is also recognised in the migration step and will create new fields based on the referred fields.

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    field_1 = modify_field(A, 'field_1', blank = True)
    field_3 = modify_field(B, 'field_3', blank = True)
```